# Pivot and annotate Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given the CSV data:

```
,fan1,fan2,foil1,foil2
0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.125
1,0.0625,0.0,0.0625,0.125
2,0.0625,0.0,0.0,0.3125
```

Which I want to turn into a kind of annotated pivot-table which can be plotted as a bar-plot:

```
,Err,PairType,StimType
0,0.0,Target,1
1,0.0625,Target,1
2,0.0625,Target,1
0,0.0,Target,2
1,0.0,Target,2
2,0.0,Target,2
0,0.0,RPFoil,1
1,0.0625,RPFoil,1
2,0.0,RPFoil,1
0,0.125,RPFoil,2
1,0.125,RPFoil,2
2,0.3125,RPFoil,2
```

I currently accomplish this with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def df_plotable(model_err: pd.DataFrame):
    t_len = len(model_err.fan1)
    cols = ("Err", "PairType", "StimType")

    fan1_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([model_err.fan1, ["Fan"]*t_len, [1]*t_len]).T,
                           columns=cols)
    fan2_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([model_err.fan2, ["Fan"]*t_len, [2]*t_len]).T,
                           columns=cols)
    foil1_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([model_err.foil1, ["Foil"]*t_len, [1]*t_len]).T,
                            columns=cols)
    foil2_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([model_err.foil2, ["Foil"]*t_len, [2]*t_len]).T,
                            columns=cols)

    new_model_err = pd.concat((fan1_df, fan2_df, foil1_df, foil2_df))
    new_model_err["Err"] = new_model_err["Err"].astype(float)
    new_model_err["StimType"] = new_model_err["StimType"].astype(int)

    return new_model_err
```

Such that:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv", "r", delimiter=",", index_col=0)
df_plotable(df).to_csv("out.csv")
```

Is there a way to do this more cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't hard-code your transformation

With your current approach, as soon as you are faced with a new PairType or StimType you will have to adjust your function accordingly to account for them. What your current code is doing is really a hard-coded version of a wide-form to long-form conversion of the column data - and Pandas has methods to allow you to do that in an automated way.

Two options would be [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), or a combination of [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Either way, after this step you'll nearly be all the way there.

```
>>> model_err.melt(var_name='PairStim', value_name='Err')

   PairStim     Err
0      fan1  0.0000
1      fan1  0.0625
2      fan1  0.0625
3      fan2  0.0000
4      fan2  0.0000
5      fan2  0.0000
6     foil1  0.0000
7     foil1  0.0625
8     foil1  0.0000
9     foil2  0.1250
10    foil2  0.1250
11    foil2  0.3125
```

The only other step in automation is to split the PairStim column up into its components, and do some cleanup. Wrapping this up in your function:

```
def longform_model_error(model_err: pd.DataFrame):            
    melted = model_err.melt(var_name='PairStim', value_name='Err')
    melted[['PairType', 'StimType']] = (
        melted['PairStim'].str.extract('(\w+)(\d+)', expand=True)
    )
    melted['PairType'] = melted['PairType'].str.capitalize()
    melted['StimType'] = melted['StimType'].astype(int)
    return melted.drop('PairStim', axis='columns')
```

---

#### Comments on your current approach

- Consider using the [`.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html) attribute on a Series (or the `.shape` attribute) instead of `len`. This makes it more clear to me that `model_err.fan1` is indeed a Pandas type.
- If you *did* want to hard-code the transformation for some reason, creating a DataFrame for each group and `concat`-ing them together is not ideal - you might as well remain in NumPy-land for as long as possible before turning it into a DataFrame. You would also benefit from hard-coding the separate columns instead of separate rows, as the dtypes of the columns are homogeneous, so you'd avoid the subsequent casting. Perhaps something like

  ```
  def longform_model_error_hardcode(model_err: pd.DataFrame):
      n_per_type = model_err.shape[0]
      pair_types = ('Fan', 'Foil')
      stim_types = (1, 2)
      n_stims = len(stim_types)

      cols = {
          'Err': model_err.values.ravel('F'),
          'PairType': np.repeat(pair_types, n_per_type*n_stims), 
          'StimType': np.tile(np.repeat(stim_types, 
                                        n_per_type), 
                              n_stims)
      }
      return pd.DataFrame(cols)
  ```

  This will be faster, though if you were to go down the hard-coding avenue there isn't really much point in using Pandas at all if you're not performing other operations on the data - might as well just stick to NumPy in that case.
- Nitpicking, `df_plotable` and `new_model_err` don't really help me understand what the function is supposed to do, or how `new_model_err` is different from the input DataFrame. Try and use some more descriptive variable names.